# Convert foreach to linq

Tags: c#, linq

Can anyone tell me how do i convert the below code to linq.I am trying to get the endpoint address from web.config file using contract name.

I need to convert below for each loop to linq .

```
string csEndPoint =null;
ClientSection clientSettings = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.serviceModel/client") as ClientSection;
   foreach (ChannelEndpointElement endpoint in clientSettings.Endpoints) {
                    if (endpoint.Contract == "CsWebService.ICsWebService") {
                        ccEndPoint = endpoint.Address.ToString();
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: I'm sure you tried something. Where/how did it fail?

Comment: I tried this 
string csEndPoint = clientSettings.Endpoints.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Contract == "CsWebService.ICsWebService")?.Address.ToString();

 but FirstOrDefault   showing error ChannelEndpointElement doenot contain a defination for first or default

Comment: Next time when you ask a question, please show what you tried and include any info on errors and failures. It was impossible to guess that `clientSettings.Endpoints` only implemented `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Linq` approach with `FirstOrDefault`

```
string csEndPoint = clientSection.Endpoints.Cast<ChannelEndpointElement>().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Contract == "CsWebService.ICsWebService")?.Address.ToString();
```

.NET 4.5 and below

```
string csEndPoint = clientSection.Endpoints.Cast<ChannelEndpointElement>()
                                 .Where(e => e.Contract == "CsWebService.ICsWebService")
                                 .Select(x => x.Address.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
string csEndPoint = (from k in clientSettings.Endpoints
         where k.Contract == "CsWebService.ICsWebService"
         select k.Address.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: if this is not working then the foreach you have mentioned should also not work.

Comment: @arunthatham `foreach` is working because of the explicit `ChannelEndpointElement` loop variable (instead of usual `var`). If you do `(from ChannelEndpointElement k in ...`, the query will work as well.

Comment: Thanks Ivan. Another thing that comes to my mind is to use a let keyword within the query and type casting the variable with ChannelEndpointElement